# Using setCentralWidget on a subclass of QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

Not sure if I'm even asking this question correctly because I'm new to C++ and Qt. But, say I have a subclass of QWidget:

```
class childofqwidget : public QWidget
```

Can I pass a pointer to an object of subclass to the setCentralWidget member function of QMainWindow? Something like this:

```
mainlayout = new childofqwidget;
setCentralWidget(mainlayout);
```

The reason I'm asking is because I've made a subclass of QWidget which has a layout with a textbox and some buttons. I'd like to insert this as the central widget of the QMainWindow object. Is this possible? If not is there a better way I should do this?

Comment: You should get into the habit of naming class names with a capital letter for each new word. `childofwidget` should be named `ChildOfWidget`. Variables and method names should begin with a lower letter and capital letter for every new word: `mainlayout` should be named `mainLayout`. (This is the Qt naming convention.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's perfectly fine, and that's the usual way to do it.

(Call a variable `layout` when it's a `widget` is a bit unusual/confusing though, but that's just naming.)

Comment: Ok cool. I tried doing this and it wouldn't compile... Compiler told me that setCentralWidget only accepts arguments of type (*QWidget). I was probably implementing something incorrectly. Let me retry...

Comment: Your snippet should work, as long as `mainlayout` is declared as `childofqwidget *mainlayout`.

Comment: Awesome. Got it to work; the previous error was due to faulty implementation on my part. Thanks.